# jQuery: appendTo only once in each match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Need to throw the contents of `span .cat` to the `div` above, but this event throws all `span .cat` to each `div`.

On the way out I get

```
date category category2 category3
date category category2 category3
date category category2 category3
```

Do I need to

```
date category
date category2
date category3
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bdt-post-grid-category').wrapInner('<span class="bdt-post-grid-date cat"></span>');
  $('.bdt-post-grid-date.cat').appendTo($(".bdt-post-grid-meta"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-meta bdt-subnav bdt-flex-middle">
  <span class="bdt-post-grid-date">date</span>
</div>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-category bdt-position-small bdt-position-top-left">
  <a href="#" rel="category tag">category</a>
</div>

<div class="bdt-post-grid-meta bdt-subnav bdt-flex-middle">
  <span class="bdt-post-grid-date">date</span>
</div>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-category bdt-position-small bdt-position-top-left">
  <a href="#" rel="category tag">category2</a>
</div>

<div class="bdt-post-grid-meta bdt-subnav bdt-flex-middle">
  <span class="bdt-post-grid-date">date</span>
</div>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-category bdt-position-small bdt-position-top-left">
  <a href="#" rel="category tag">category3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.each()` to process each of them separately, just appending to the previous element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bdt-post-grid-category').wrapInner('<span class="bdt-post-grid-date cat"></span>');
  $('.bdt-post-grid-date.cat').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).closest(".bdt-post-grid-category").prev());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-meta bdt-subnav bdt-flex-middle">
  <span class="bdt-post-grid-date">date</span>
</div>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-category bdt-position-small bdt-position-top-left">
  <a href="#" rel="category tag">category</a>
</div>

<div class="bdt-post-grid-meta bdt-subnav bdt-flex-middle">
  <span class="bdt-post-grid-date">date</span>
</div>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-category bdt-position-small bdt-position-top-left">
  <a href="#" rel="category tag">category2</a>
</div>

<div class="bdt-post-grid-meta bdt-subnav bdt-flex-middle">
  <span class="bdt-post-grid-date">date</span>
</div>
<div class="bdt-post-grid-category bdt-position-small bdt-position-top-left">
  <a href="#" rel="category tag">category3</a>
</div>
```